# Export to excel and display chart

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart, jexcelapi

I am developing this application that requires me to provide an option to export to excel and generate graphs in the excel based on user choice.Now i have used a combination of JExcel and JFreechart to generate the excel sheet and display graph.
What I am unable to do is to generate graph for particular columns as I need to provide range of cells.

Hence is there any other alternative way to do this ? 
I need to write generic code to display data and graph so that it will be applicable for all types of data.

Comment: The diagrams could be done in Excel too.

Comment: When the excel file gets created, it must also have the graph. I cannot open the file and then create the graph

Comment: *"..generate graphs in the excel based on user choice."*  If I was the user with the choice, I'd choose Open Office over Excel.

Comment: In the UI I will be providing the user with an option to select the type of graph and also the columns.

Comment: why not export the graph from JFreeChart?

Comment: You could make one export of data only, add a diagram manually in Excel, and use that excel as template. If .xslx is possible, you have a zip file with XML, which - with much effort - is customizable.

Comment: @robthewolf : Yup that is what I am doing Currently.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: I can't do that as the data on my JSP is not fixed i.e. the columns vary from names to data type. It is all generic.

Comment: I don't have idea about Jfree chart API but i have used Smartxls API, that allows continuous specified range of cells and usages of this API is very simple, if your interested i will post the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.php
 <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
  </form>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { 
      require_once 'dbConfig.php';
      require_once 'excel_reader/excel_reader.php';
      $excel = new PhpExcelReader();

        $file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $excel->read($file); 
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($excel);
        // echo '<pre>';print_r($excel->sheets[0]['cells']);
         //echo '<pre>'; print_r($excel->sheets[0]['numCols']);
         //echo '<pre>'; print_r($excel->sheets[0]['numRows']);
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][2][1]);

         $coloms=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols'];
         $rows=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows'];
        //  $cell = $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$j][$i] ;


      for($i=3;$i<=$rows;)
      {
      for($j=1;$j<=$coloms;)
      {
          $cell = ($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]);
          $j++;

        }
            $name = ($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1]) ;

            $roll_no = ($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2]);

            $hobbies = ($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3]) ; 

          $i++;
          //echo $name;
          //echo $roll_no;
          //echo $hobbies;
          echo  $r = "INSERT INTO fileupload(name,roll_no,hobbies) VALUES('".$name."','".$roll_no."','".$hobbies."')";
          $result = mysqli_query($con,$r);

        }
       echo "<script>alert('Inserted Successfully');window.location.href = 'upload.php'</script>";


      }

    ?>
  </body>
</html>

upload.php


<table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Roll no</td>
    <td>Hobbies</td>

    </tr>
 <?php

 require_once 'dbConfig.php';
 $sql="SELECT name,roll_no,hobbies FROM fileupload";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($con,$sql);?>

    <?php
   $hobbies='';
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
 {  

  ?>



        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['roll_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php $hobbies.=$row['hobbies'].','; echo $row['hobbies'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php


 }

 $hobbies= explode(',',rtrim($hobbies,','));
 $hobbies= array_count_values($hobbies);

 foreach ($hobbies as $key => $value) 
 {
    $key .'-'.$value.'<br>';
    }
    ?>




<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load Charts and the corechart and barchart packages.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Draw the pie chart and bar chart when Charts is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
         <?php 

         foreach ($hobbies as $key => $value) 
          {?>

          ['<?php echo $key ;?>',<?php echo $value;?>],
         <?php }?>

        ]);

        var piechart_options = {title:'Activities',
                       width:400,
                       height:300};
        var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_div'));
        piechart.draw(data, piechart_options);

        var barchart_options = {title:'Activities',
                       width:400,
                       height:300,
                       legend: 'none'};
        var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
         var chart = new google.visualization.ImageLineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data,linechart_options );
      }
</script>
<body>
    <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="piechart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        <td><div id="barchart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        <td><div id="chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```